# How do you test an HTTP server running on a Compute Engine instance without exposing it to the public?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using a Compute Engine as my main development machine, I would like to start testing my application, however, if I assign it an external IP address then it will be open to the public web which is a privacy concern of mine.

Assuming that I will not be accessing this instance from the same IP address  every time, how can I go about being able to test HTTP requests for the development that I am doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ssh port forwarding to set up a proxy from your laptop to the machine. If you are using Mac or Linux `ssh`, something like the following should work to forward port 8080 from your local machine to the VM ([from the gcloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh)):

```
gcloud compute ssh --ssh_flag="-L 80:%INSTANCE%:80"
```

Once you've set this up, you can access the server at http://localhost: 8080/ on your laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that your IP address is not fixed.

The first method is to configure the Google VPC firewall to your current IP address. Then as you IP address changes, update the VPC firewall rule. This is the simplest method and only takes a minute or two but you must do this every time your address changes.

If your public IP address changes but is within a range then you can configure the firewall rule with a CIDR block instead of a single IP address.

The preferred method is to not assign the instance a public IP address. Install a VPN gateway in your VPC and the VPN client on your desktop. Your web browser and tools will then use the VPN to connect to the private IP address. Google Marketplace has free VPN software, such as OpenVPN which I use. You just pay for the instance time, which you can shut down when you don't need a VPN.

There are more sophisticated methods, such as token authorization, but this is overkill for web server testing.